# Capturing events from another module with on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, dom-events, eventemitter

I am using a module called `request`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to perform series of http requests on my application. Now I am trying to add a logging functionality to it but cannot seem to figure out how to capture the events from the request module. I can do the event capturing like so:

```
var request = require('request');

request('http://www.stackoverflow.com').on('request', function (data) {
  console.log(data.method + ":" + data._headers.host);
}).on('response', function (data) {
  console.log("Status: " + data.statusCode);
});
```

This will produce output of:

> $ node test.js
> GET:[www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
> GET:stackoverflow.com
> Status: 200

How can I capture the events without specifying it after the `request()` call? Ideally I would like to only have to require `request` module and some other file which would contain all the listeners for request events and start using `request` without worrying about the event handling. So the end result would look in the code files something like:

```
var request = require('request');
var requestLogger = require('reqLogger')(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`request` readme](https://github.com/request/request#debugging), there are at least a few different ways to get debug information from `request`. The third solution in particular (using [`request-debug`](https://github.com/request/request-debug)) seems to get you exactly what you're currently trying to do.

Comment: Ah, I seemed to have missed that completely. Thank you for pointing that out!